# SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Statement is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Statement is closed

Tags: java, mybatis

I have two databases with Mybatis. I have a find with mybatis. But Sometimes I have a exception:
SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Statement is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Statement is closed. It's not always happen.

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Statement is closed.
### The error may exist in file [D:\code\xx\target\classes\mapper\Person.xml]
### The error may involve xx.xx.xx.findPersonCnt
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: select  count(*)     from    person b      
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Statement is closed.
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Statement is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Statement is closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:139)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.findPersonCnt(Unknown Source)
```

**One Config**

```
    @Configuration
// 配置mybatis的接口类放的地方
@MapperScan(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.mapper", sqlSessionFactoryRef = "oneSqlSessionFactory")
public class TwoSourceConfig {
    // 将这个对象放入Spring容器中
    @Bean(name = "oneDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "one.datasource")
    public DataSource getIgniteDateSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "oneSqlSessionFactory")
    @Primary
    // @Qualifier表示查找Spring容器中名字为igniteDataSource的对象
    public SqlSessionFactory igniteSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("oneDataSource") DataSource datasource)
            throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(datasource);
        bean.setMapperLocations(
                // 设置mybatis的xml所在位置
                new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:mapper/*.xml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }
    @Bean("oneSqlSessionTemplate")
    // 表示这个数据源是默认数据源
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate ignitesqlsessiontemplate(
            @Qualifier("igniteSqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sessionfactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sessionfactory);
    }
}
```

**Two Config**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.xx.mapper", sqlSessionFactoryRef = "twoSqlSessionFactory")
public class TwoDataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "twoDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "two.datasource")
    public DataSource getDateSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "twoSqlSessionFactory")
    public SqlSessionFactory tidbSqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("twoDataSource") DataSource datasource)
            throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(datasource);
        bean.setMapperLocations(
                new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:mapping/*.xml"));
        return bean.getObject();
    }
    @Bean("twoSqlSessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate tidbsqlsessiontemplate(
            @Qualifier("tidbSqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sessionfactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sessionfactory);
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this exception?

Comment: Please add the versions of Java and any dependencies you use.

Comment: jdk8 and springboot 2.0.7.RELEASE

Comment: This version of Spring Boot is not supported, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions).

Comment: @zhangzl The stack trace looks incomplete. Please include the full stack trace.